# Is "North.5" the same as "0.5"?

Tags: word-meaning, spoken-english

I've just heard a native English speaker saying this:

> "North.5"

which means:

> 0.5

I mean seriously?! What kind of number is that? I may have misheard him but in mathematics, I've never heard of this one before, so it must be regional. Please clarify.

Answer (score 11):

You must have heard "nought", a mainly British name for the "zero" digit. It rhymes with caught, ought, etc. "Nought point five" is a typically British way of saying aloud what is written as "0.5". In figures, you write one million as a one followed by six noughts. British people sometimes refer to the decade that started in 2000 as 'the noughties'.

> nought
>
> number (ZERO) ​ [ C ]
>
> mainly UK (USA usually naught) the number 0 or
>   zero:
>
> He said it was only worth £10, but really you could add a couple of
>   noughts to that (= it is really worth £1,000).

[Nought (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nought)